# Which WPF Layout and Controls Should I Use for a Storyboard Effect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to create a layout that has small panels at the top and bottom and then a main panel in the center that fills the remainder of the window.  The main window should have the functionality of a tab panel but instead of simple tabs I want the tab pages to slide on and off the screen.  It will be like one large storyboard that slides back and forth and only displays one scene at a time.

So lets assume there are 4 tab pages.  Initially the first page will be visible, the 2nd page will be directly off the screen to the right, the 3rd page will be 2 pages off the screen to the right and the 4th page will be 3 pages off the screen to the right.  When the user clicks to see the 3rd tab page the layout will slide left 2 pages.  Then if the user clicks to see page 1 again, the page will slide back right 2 pages.

The window needs to be resizeable, so I can't use fixed sizes and offset.

Do I just need to use a StackPanel and programmatically set width, height, and position or is there something built-in that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hrrrm the first idea that comes to mind is use a `ScrollViewer` and hide the `ScrollBars`.

You could then display all your items in a `StackPanel` in the `ScrollViewer`, and when you want to scroll an item into view, simply animate the ScrollViewer's position so it smoothly scrolls to the specified item.